# git no toma los cambios que realizo

Tags: git

Buen día, tengo el siguiente problema con git en VScode, descargue un repositorio remoto este tiene varias ramas, en el momento que descargo una rama y voy a empezar a trabajar este no toma los cambios, no se puede realizar commit.

Tengo permisos para el repositorio.

Lo que hago es que clono el repositorio, este me coloca en la rama main, por ejemplo bajo los cambios que esta rama tiene con git pull origin y funciona bien, bajo otra rama con git fetch origin ajustes:ajustes y efectivamente descarga la rama del repositorio remoto, pero en el momento que comienzo a realizar cambios, los archivos no muestran la M que sale en sus archivos que significa modificado, y cambio de rama y se puede sin realizar el commit.

Si coloco git status sale como si no tuviera modificaciones.

Ya intente desinstalar VScode, elimine las ramas, las volví a descargar y aún no tengo éxito.

Siempre sale como si no tuviera cambios.

Para descargar las ramas utilice el siguiente comando git fetch nombreRama:nombreRama

Comment: Seria ideal que coloques el comando completo que ejecutaste junto con su salida en la pregunta.

Comment: Con respecto a que no puedes hacer commit, podrías colocar la salida de `git status` antes de hacer commit y el comando con el que intentas hacer commit y su salida? Todo ello, en la pregunta original, por favor.

Comment: Pregunta complementada  @eftshift0

Comment: Lo que me hace ruido.. es que tiene que ver vscode en todo esto?

Comment: cambiar de rama, se puede aunque hayas modificado cosas.. sin ninguna clase de problemas.. Las M.. puede ser cualquier otro problema... hiciste un clone..podrias ponernos el status luego de modificar cualquier archivo en una rama.. y si agregas uno nuevo???

Comment: Es el editor que utilizo para ser un poco más descriptivo @gbianchi